# Cannot make same AJAX call from script file that I could locally

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm working in C# MVC 5

I have a `Main.cshtml` page that contains a number of Partial Views.
One of these Partial Views, `Child`, loads in more Partial Views, `Grandchild`, into itself

```cs
if (Model.ChildViewModel.GrandchildViewModels.Count == 0)
{
    { Html.RenderPartial("_PartialGrandchild", new GrandchildViewModel()); }
}
else
{
    foreach (var grandchildViewModel in Model.ChildViewModel.GrandchildViewModels)
    {
        { Html.RenderPartial("_PartialGrandchild", grandchildViewModel); }
    }
}
<div id="newGrandchild"></div>
<div class="row">
    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary btn-block" type="button" onclick="addGrandchild('#newGrandchild')">Add A Grandchild</button>
</div>
```

If look at the 2nd to last line, you see a button with an `onclick` event linked to `addGranchild('#newGrandchild')`. This calls my AJAX function to add another Grandchild Partial View above my `newGrandchild` div.

That AJAX function is shown here:

```js
function addGrandchild(divToReplace) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("AddGrandchild", "Home")',
        data: {},
        type: "POST",
        error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Request: " + xmlHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $(divToReplace).before(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Which in turn calls my `HomeController`'s method `AddGrandchild` shown here:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult AddGrandchild()
{
    return PartialView("_PartialGrandchild", new GrandchildViewModel());
}
```

**My problem:**
I'm not hitting my breakpoint in my `HomeController` and I'm getting this error in my AJAX's alert:

> Request: [object Object]
>   Status: error
>   Error: Not Found

Before, I was leaving this JavaScript in the `Main.cshtml` at the bottom in a `<script>` section. Now I have moved it over to a file named `mainFunctions.js` and I'm referencing it in `Main.cshtml` with `<script src="~/Scripts/Custom/mainFunctions.js"></script>` at the bottom where it is the last script loaded.

My other functions so far look alright, but only my AJAX calls have stopped working.

Why is that?

Comment: I suspect the `Url.Action` call is returning the relative URL. What happens if you change the `url` value in your ajax call to `'@Url.Action("AddGrandchild", "Home", null, Request.Url.Scheme)'`?

Comment: No changes unfortunately

Comment: If you open your browser's developer tools, what do you see in the network information about the call? Is it targeting the correct resource?

Comment: Looks like it's going to: `https://localhost:44397/Home/@Url.Action("AddGrandchild", "Home", null, Request.Url.Scheme)` Is the `@Url.Action` supposed to be there? I'm still farily new to web dev so I haven't used the Network tab a whole lot. I can also tell you it's getting a 404 error (which explains the `Not Found` error).

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to use Razor code in a javascript file.

Comment: I think you're right. Changing the Request URL in the network tab to `https://localhost:44397/Home/AddGrandchild` and resending it hits my Home Controller, but I'm not seeing anything being added on the View. Hmmm

Comment: That's exactly what's happening. I'd add a url parameter to your addGrandchild function and pass in the value on the button's `onClick` method.

Comment: I didn't even need to do that, seems just changing the `url` value to `/Home/AddGrandchild` does the trick. I made it a community wiki answer post below. Thank you guys for helping me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [Jonathon Chase](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5402620/jonathon-chase) and [charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl) comments, it was realized I was using Razor syntax in my JavaScript file causing my AJAX's `url` property to be taken literally and send me to `https://{whateverMyUrlMyBe.com}/@Url.Action("AddGrandchild", "Home")`, which couldn't be found and returned a 404 error.

To fix this, all I had to do was change the `url` value to this:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/AddGrandchild',
    ...
});
```

Comment: You should always use the `@Url.Action()` method to ensure your url's are correctly generated. There a many ways to do this from the main view, including adding a `data-url="@Url.Action(...)"` attribute in your `<button>` and using `$(yourButton).click(function(){ var url = $(this).data('url'); ...`